# Movie about a serial killer who drowns his victims

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have seen this movie on HBO, between 10- 12 years ago. At that time I was not a Hollywood movie buff but I really liked the story. This was a suspense movie and am guessing it must have been made in between 1990 -2000.

There was a killer in the movie who drops live girls with heavy weights tied to their legs into a river. One lucky girl is saved by some cops driving by the river. Then they create a life size dummy of the girl and put cameras in the dummy's eyes. When the killer comes back to the river to check the girl's body, cops get his picture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Cabin by the Lake](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0199389/) (2000)?

A screenwriter does research for his new script by actually kidnapping and drowning young girls. He then places them in his "garden" of other dead girls coming back daily to check on them. One girl narrowly escapes and the other bodies are found leading to an ingenious plot to try and capture the killer.